# Using the methods of a compressed .Net DLL without extract it to hard disk

Tags: c#, .net, dll, password-protection

**Step 1:**
I want compress some of my .Net `DLL` files (some built class libraries) as `Zip` or `7z` and protect theme by a password, i can do this manually by some utilities for windows like 7z application.

The project files before applying the scenario:

- `App.exe`
- `A.dll`
- `B.dll`

The final files after applying the first step of scenario:

- `App.exe`
- `X.zip` (*password protected & compressed archive file*)

and `X.zip` is contain `A.dll` & `B.dll`

---

**Step 2:** Now, i want know is there a way to extract `A.dll` & `B.dll` directly to RAM (Not to HDD) and use their methods by `App.exe`???

I want keep these `Dll` files Secure during this scenario and prevent copy theme from HDD by users, so i want use their functionalists after loading theme to RAM.

---

**Edit:**

I usualy use these technologies: `C#`, `WPF`, `.Net 4.5`

Comment: Maybe [`Assembly.Load(byte[])`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/h538bck7%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is what you're looking for.

Comment: If `App.exe` can obtain the binaries, so can a determined user. Are you sure you're not just introducing complexity that won't just negatively impact your actual users? The only way to keep code secure is to not hand it to the users at all (i.e. have it on a server and have the client application talk to the server)

Comment: I use another method to secure App.exe. my dll file is contain some info that is important for us...

Comment: More to the point, I'm assuming you will have the password in your code? If so and given that .NET apps compile to IL it would relatively easy to de-compile your application find the decompression code and hence the password and then just unzip using normal tools. (Edit: Sorry saw your last comment after I posted this...)

Answer (score 2):

I think you can use the AppDomain.AssemblyResolve event.

When your assemblies are requested, extract them from your zip in memory into a byte array. Use the Assembly.Load(byte[]) overload to load an assembly from an in-memory byte array, and return the assembly.

See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.assemblyresolve%28v=vs.110%29.aspx and https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h538bck7(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Correct for the "how to load assembly into memory part", still if we're talking about security part of question; I don't think there is a way how you can prevent user from taking a memory snapshot and store assembly to disk/analyze it. Only way how to partially achieve this is to obsfuculate the dlls.

Comment: Yes, but there is some ways to break obsfuculate. specialy i want keep secure my resources and dlls of copy from HDD...

Answer (score 2):

As for the load in to memory I can see that @Maarten has a good point in terms of using the [`Assembly.Load(byte\[\])`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/h538bck7%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method.

My opinion and advice is to never store anything sensitive in your code/dlls directly. I've read somewhere and I stay by the same saying:

> "There are no secrets in .NET"

So, you can always decompile in IL, reverse engineer sort of speak, no matter how cleverly you try to obfuscate it. You can only save on time, when it comes to clever users.

**(Some) Solutions:**

Now, for the solutions. If I understand correctly you are trying to protect some sensitive info inside your dll, that after deployment to the user, in an offline fashion, you don' want them to access. There are tons of questions and even more possible explanations on SO about this topic, but it all comes down to a handful that you can try:

- Putting the sensitive information in a separate file with limited access
- You can for example put a COM or C++ dll for storing encrypted strings. A unmanaged dll is not decompilable, however, expert people can of course understand the disassembly of a dll.
- You can use some sort of internal in-process db, but someone can still sniff out the connection to it and get to the data

...and so on and so forth.

**Conclusion:**

In the end, I believe that a more secure option might be to provide the critical part of your software as a service, some sort of access to an API that you can secure and access the sensitive information trough it, rather than include it in your application, if that is possible.

Comment: Yes, i agree with you in _"There are no secrets in .NET"_, but some times we want secure our methods and our resources together. i have a solution to secure the `EXE` file and i usualy packs my `DLLs` inside my `EXE` but in this project i want have several `EXE` and share my `DLLs` between themes, so i must keep theme outside of the `EXE`. Now i want have a secure level over these dll and resources. Now I'm using `Assembly.Load(byte\[\])` with `DotNetZip` library together. Also i'm interested in `internal in-process` methods but i have not enough knowledge about it, then i used `Assembly.Load`

Comment: If you need to share some data from the dlls between different apps you could try something like Memory-Mapped Files: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997372.aspx maybe?